# Angular2 generates error - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am following the Tour of Heroes tutorial. Instead of `getHero()` I have a `getCustomer()` method. I am getting the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error? I think there may be a problem with the `handleError()` function.

### customer-detail.component.ts

```
getCustomer(id: string): void {
    this.customerService.getCustomer(id)
        .subscribe(
            customer => this.customer = customer,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}
```

### customer.service.ts

```
getCustomer(id: string): Observable<Customer> {
    const url = `${this.customerUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;

    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);

    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Comment: Is `''} ${err}` a valid syntax in `errMsg = ..` line?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)

It shoud work
 Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes" so the view will be updated with the new value